# Which SLF4 Logging jar do I need for BoneCP?

Tags: slf4j, bonecp

There are a dozen SLF4 jars within the project and I can't tell which I need to run BoneCP. Is it just slf4j-simple-xxx.jar, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can chose any slf4j binding, e.g. slf4j-nop, slf4j-simple, logback-classic, slf4j-log4j12 or slf4j-jdk14. Just pick one, any one.